# Oracle SQL join two tables based on condition and find minimum value

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider Table A

| ID | date_identifier |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1900 |
| b | 2020 |

and Table B:

| ID | date_identifier |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1901 |
| a | 1705 |
| b | 2020 |
| b | 500 |
| d | 3000 |

What i find to do is to left join both tables and get the minimum date_identifier from Table B
where A.ID not in B.ID and B.date_identifier>A.date_identifier

Expected Result:

| ID | date_identifier_a | min_date_identifier_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1900 | 2020 |
| b | 2020 | 3000 |

Is there any better option than the following?

```
select
  a.*,
  (select min(b.date_identifier) 
   from b 
   where a.ID not in b.ID 
   and a.date_identifier < b.date_identifier
  )
from a
```

Comment: Your query looks very good. Just change `a.ID not in b.ID` to `a.ID <> b.ID`, because there is no data set involved, you are merely comparing two values.

Comment: I am surprised that `NOT IN` doesn't result in a syntax error here. It does in PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL and probably most other DBMS. Oracle is quite merciful here.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use a join a `LATERAL` inline view and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.date_identifier AS date_identifier_a,
       b.date_identifier AS min_date_identifier_b
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT date_identifier
         FROM   table_b b
         WHERE  a.id != b.id
         AND    a.date_identifier < b.date_identifier
         ORDER BY date_identifier ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) b
       ON (1 = 1)
```

In earlier versions, you could use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id,
       date_identifier_a,
       date_identifier_b AS min_date_identifier_b
FROM   (
  SELECT a.id,
         a.date_identifier AS date_identifier_a,
         b.date_identifier AS date_identifier_b,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ROWID ORDER BY b.date_identifier) AS rn
  FROM   table_a a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
         ON (   a.id != b.id
            AND a.date_identifier < b.date_identifier)
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (ID, date_identifier) AS
SELECT 'a', 1900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2020 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (ID, date_identifier) AS
SELECT 'a', 1901 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1705 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2020 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 3000 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | DATE_IDENTIFIER_A | MIN_DATE_IDENTIFIER_B |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 1900 | 2020 |
> | b | 2020 | 3000 |

You can profile the different solutions with your tables/indexes/statistics and see if any is more performant as they all have (very) different explain plans.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4d61c144f5abe85d398d5e051706d392)*

Comment: Just a note, you join a _lateral derived table_. I.e. the LATERAL keyword belongs to the subquery, not to the JOIN.

Comment: Well, I only know the term "lateral join" for joining a correlated subquery. I've never heard the term "lateral derived table". Anyway, while it is possible to use a lateral join here, I see no benefit over the OPs query with a subquery in the select clause. It's simply an alternative. It would be beneficial if we wanted more than that one column from table b. The question was "Is there any better option" and the answer could be "a lateral join does the same, but contrary to the subquery in the select clause, it can get you more than just one column from the top row".

Comment: @jarlh The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) uses the terminology "Specify `LATERAL` to designate subquery as a lateral inline view. Within a lateral inline view, you can specify tables that appear to the left of the lateral inline view in the `FROM` clause of a query." So the `LATERAL` keyword has to appear in the `FROM` clause as part of a join to an inline view; there is nothing about "derived tables" in the documentation.

Comment: That _inline view_, is what ISO/ANSI SQL calls a _derived table_. (Feature T491, “LATERAL derived table”.)

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for telling me where you get the terminology from. I'll stick with the terminology in either the Oracle documentation ("join a lateral inline view") or the common vernacular (simplifying Oracle's statement to "a lateral join" and omitting the implicit fact that a lateral join must be performed on an inline view). Given that an inline view and a derived table are [the same thing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Unnesting-of-Nested-Subqueries.html) then we're what talking about is identical.

Comment: From what I understand, an inline view is the same as a derived table - a subqeury in the FROM clause.